# How to make crawlable links in a single pare application in react js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, seo

I am making a website in nextjs and reactjs. The website is this https://www.codingconquerors.com/. When I check the lighthouse report, it gives me an err that "links are not crawlable". It is a SPA. I am almost googling from last 4 days but still not able to figure out the solution for this. Below code is displaying the navigation bar:

```
{navigation.map((item) => (
                <Link
                  spy={true}
                  smooth={true}
                  key={item.name}
                  to={item.href}
                  className="font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900"
                >
                  {item.name}
                </Link>
              ))}
```

The above link tag is from this `import import { Link } from 'react-scroll'`

Even I tried using Nextjs Link tag instead of reactjs it still does not fix the issue.

The source code generated behind the link tag does not show use of href tag.
Is there any way I can fix this SEO issue? Or I have to live with this since it is a SPA.

Comment: Have you tried passing an `href` prop to the `Link` components?

Comment: Hi @juliomalves i tried but that opens up a new page. but mine is SPA. Also, if I tries href='#id' then lighthouse also shows the same err.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to display the link tags normally without using # and then had to add onclick event in react which appends # in front of the tag values. I am not sure about the approach if it is correct or not but it solves my SEO reports. And now it is 100%

Comment: Hi @khush, have you an explicit example please, with detailed code ?
I discover Next and i've same issue with SEO. 
Big thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue, pls provide some code of how you add the onClick event

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not related to the above tag, upon checking the lighthouse report, I found that the nav links in the header are anchor tags without links which is causing the following issue.

[image: Lighthouse SEO Analysis]

Which are these:
[image: Links without href]

[image: Code for nav links]

Comment: thanks for the reply Yash. Actually, these anchor tags are being generated from the Link tag which I mentioned in the question. Link tag is wrap in <nav> tag.

Answer (score 0):

if you trying to fix this with empty 'href' anchors (on WordPress, like me!), try this with custom JS:

```
/* fill empty anchors */
jQuery('a:not([href]), a[href=""]').attr('href', '#');
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is to add the **'href'** to the Link, in my case: **href='#projects'**

```
<Link
     href='#projects'
     to="projects"
     smooth={true}
     duration={500}
     offset={-50}>

     <button className="axil-btn btn-fill-primary btn-fluid btn-primary">
         See More
     </button>
</Link>
```

I was having the exact same problem on lighthouse and this solved it.
The react-scroll version I'm using is "react-scroll": "^1.9.0"